# GetCrossReferenceItems in msword and VBA showing only limited content

Tags: vba, ms-word

I want to make a special list of figures with use of VBA and here I am using the function

```
myFigures = ActiveDocument.GetCrossReferenceItems(Referencetype:="Figure")
```

In my word document there are 20 figures, but myFigures only contains the first 10 figures (see my code below.).

I search the internet and found that others had the same problem, but I have not found any solutions.

My word is 2003 version

Please help me ....

```
Sub List()

Dim i As Long

Dim LowerValFig, UpperValFig As Integer

Dim myTables, myFigures as  Variant

If ActiveDocument.Bookmarks.Count >= 1 Then

    myFigures = ActiveDocument.GetCrossReferenceItems(Referencetype:="Figure")
    ' Test size...
    LowerValFig = LBound(myFigures) 'Get the lower boundry number.
    UpperValFig = UBound(myFigures) 'Get the upper boundry number
    ' Do something ....
    For i = LBound(myFigures) To UBound(myFigures) ‘ should be 1…20, but is onlu 1…10
           'Do something ....
    Next i
End If
MsgBox ("Done ....")

End Sub*
```

Answer (score 2):

Definitely something flaky with that.  If I run the following code on a document that contains 32 Figure captions, the message boxes both display 32.  However, if I uncomment the For Next loop, they only display 12 and the iteration ceases after the 12th item.

```
Dim i As Long

Dim myFigures As Variant

myFigures = ActiveDocument.GetCrossReferenceItems("Figure")
MsgBox myFigures(UBound(myFigures))
MsgBox UBound(myFigures)
'For i = 1 To UBound(myFigures)
'    MsgBox myFigures(i)
'Next i
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with my custom cross-refference dialog and solved it by invoking the dialog after each command ActiveDocument.GetCrossReferenceItems(YourCaptionName).

So you type:

```
varRefItemsFigure1 = ActiveDocument.GetCrossReferenceItems(g_strCaptionLabelFigure1)
  For k = 1 To UBound(varRefItemsFigure1)
    frmBwtRefDialog.ListBoxFigures.AddItem varRefItemsFigure1(k)
  Next
```

and then:

```
frmBwtRefDialog.Show vbModeless
```

Thus the dialog invoked several times instead of one, but it works fast and don't do any trouble. I used this for one year and didn't see any errors.

Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

Frankly I feel bad about calling this an "answer", but here's what I did in the same situation. It would appear that entering the debugger and stepping through the GetCrossReferenceItems *always* returns the correct value. Inspired by this I tried various ways of giving control back to Word (DoEvents; running next segment using Application.OnTime) but to no avail. Eventually the only thing I found that worked was to invoke the debugger between assignments, so I have:

> availRefs =
>   ActiveDocument.GetCrossReferenceItems(wdRefTypeNumberedItem):Stop
>
> availTables =
>   ActiveDocument.GetCrossReferenceItems(wdCaptionTable):Stop
>
> availFigures = ActiveDocument.GetCrossReferenceItems(wdCaptionFigure)

It's not pretty but, as I'm the only person who'll be running this, it kind of works for my purposes.