# GetCrossReferenceItems with custom captions

Tags: vba, ms-word

In my Word file, I want to distinguish between figures in the text and figures in the Appendix by calling the second type of figure "Figure A". To refer to them properly by their ID, I want to create an array with all of my custom captions. Yet, GetCrossReferenceItems doesn't seem to work here. How can I correctly make my array?

```
Sub Caption_Example()

CaptionLabels.Add Name:="Figure"
CaptionLabels.Add Name:="Figure A"

' Insert new figure caption
With Selection
    .InsertCaption _
        Label:="Figure", _
        Title:=": A fancy title", _
        Position:=wdCaptionPositionBelow, _
        ExcludeLabel:=0
End With

' Insert a line break
Selection = vbCrLf

' Insert new figure A caption
With Selection
    .InsertCaption _
        Label:="Figure A", _
        Title:=": Another fancy title", _
        Position:=wdCaptionPositionBelow, _
        ExcludeLabel:=0
End With


' Usually to get a list of Figures I would type:
x = (ActiveDocument.GetCrossReferenceItems(ReferenceType:="Figure"))
Debug.Print "First figure: "; x(1)

' But it doesn't work with figure A
'y = (ActiveDocument.GetCrossReferenceItems(ReferenceType:="Figure A"))  ' Doesnt work at all
y = (ActiveDocument.GetCrossReferenceItems(ReferenceType = "Figure A")) ' Work, shows everything, not only Figure A

' Insert a line break (doesn't work anymore)
Selection.Text = vbCrLf

' Yet, referring to it works
    Selection.InsertCrossReference _
        ReferenceType:="Figure A", _
        ReferenceKind:=wdOnlyLabelAndNumber, _
        ReferenceItem:="1", _
        InsertAsHyperlink:=True, _
        IncludePosition:=False, _
        SeparateNumbers:=False, _
        SeparatorString:=" "


End Sub
```

Edit: `GetCrossReferenceItems` seems to work if I call the new CaptionLabel "FigureA", hence, get rid of the space in its name. But then all figures are called FigureA.1 etc.

Comment: Did you read the the documentation for GetCrossReference? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.document.getcrossreferenceitems. The parameter is an enum not a string (WdReferenceType). Furthermore captions are no cross references.

Comment: I have read the documentation but it doesn't align with what works since ```ActiveDocument.GetCrossReferenceItems(ReferenceType:="Figure")``` works quite well. What would be an alternative? About your second comment: I assumed that because if I use Word's interface to refer to a caption and track the changes, VBA uses ```InsertCrossReference```

Comment: That's really weird ... have you seen this post https://stackoverflow.com/q/949516/16578424 plus the answers ... it looks like there is no straight way to achieve what you want.

Comment: Wow, I have seen it but didn't read it yet. Now reading it in detail, it seems super weird. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I found the solution. First of all, you have to set heading 7 to look like "Appendix A". (I use heading 7 because I do not use such headings for my normal text. Attention: "Heading" is written in German "Überschrift").  Then, the following code works:

```
Sub solution()

' Make a level 7 heading
    Selection.TypeText Text:="Some heading"
    Selection.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("Überschrift 7")
    Selection.TypeParagraph

' Create captionlabel
    CaptionLabels.Add Name:="FigureA"
    With CaptionLabels("FigureA")
        .NumberStyle = wdCaptionNumberStyleArabic
        .IncludeChapterNumber = True  ' Include Chapter Nr., like A, B, ...
        .ChapterStyleLevel = 7 ' Because my chapter level 7 are the Appendix headings.
        .Separator = wdSeparatorPeriod
    End With

' Insert new figureA caption
    With Selection
        .InsertCaption _
            Label:="FigureA", _
            Title:=": Another fancy title", _
            Position:=wdCaptionPositionBelow, _
            ExcludeLabel:=True   ' Should be true
            
    End With
    
' Name it "Figure"
    With Selection.Paragraphs(1).Range
        .InsertBefore "Figure "
    End With


' Refer to that figure
    Selection.TypeParagraph
    Selection.TypeText Text:="Refer to that by writing "
    With Selection
        .InsertCrossReference _
            ReferenceType:="FigureA", _
            ReferenceKind:=wdOnlyLabelAndNumber, _
            ReferenceItem:=1, _
            InsertAsHyperlink:=True, _
            IncludePosition:=False, _
            SeparateNumbers:=False, _
            SeparatorString:=" "
    End With

End Sub
```

Edit: The problem seems to be the space between "Figure" and "A" in the caption label.